# Python Guessing game, ValueError: empty range for randrange()

Tags: python

I have seen many if statements and while loop questions, but haven't found any that were related to my problem.
In school we were challenged to do a guessing game, but the computer had to guess our number. The teacher gave us an answer, but I wasn't happy and decided to do it my way. In trying to do so, an error occurred.

**My error is:**

```
Guess2 = str(random.randint(Guess2, Number+1))
File "C:\Users\Diogo Melim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py", 
line 220, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\Diogo Melim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py", line 198, in randrange
raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (188315,32, -188283)
```

```
import random

def guessing_game():

  Number = int(input())
  Number2 = str(Number)
  Guess = int(random.randint(1, 1000000))
  Guess2 =  str(Guess)

  while Guess2 != Number2 :

      Number2
      print( "My guess is " + Guess2)

      if Guess2 > Number2:
          print ("Wrong, " + Guess2)
          Guess2 = int(Guess2)
          Guess2 = str(random.randint(Number-1, Guess2))
          print("I'll try again, it's less") 
      elif Guess2 < Number2:
          print ("Errei, " + Guess2)
          Guess2 = int(Guess2)
          Guess2 = str(random.randint(Guess2, Number+1))
          print("I'll try again, it's bigger")
      elif Guess2 == Number2 :
          print( "Got it, the value was: " + Guess2)
          break
  else :
      print( "Got it! The value was:  " + Number2)
      exit

guessing_game()
```

Comment: `empty range for randrange()` ... self explanatory, your numbers are the same or `x == y` in `randint(x, y)`

Comment: Your posted code fails to run: Numero is not defined.

Comment: I made a typo, Numero is number, i was trying to translate it to english and screwed up, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic logic problem is that you compare string values, rather than numeric values.  You can't reasonably call **randint** on a pair of strings.

Strings sort character by character.  For instance, "2" is greater than "10", because it doesn't look past the first difference: "2" vs "1".  This drives your guessing values out of range, and eventually leaves you with the upper and lower guessing bounds inverted.

The only place you *need* strings in your code is to grab the input.  After that, just work with the integer values:

```
import random

def guessing_game():

  Number = int(input())
  Guess = int(random.randint(1, 1000000))

  while Guess != Number :

      print( "My guess is " + Guess)

      if Guess > Number:
          print ("Wrong, " + Guess)
          Guess = int(Guess)
          Guess = random.randint(Number-1, Guess)
          print("I'll try again, it's less") 
      elif Guess < Number:
          print ("Errei, " + Guess)
          Guess = int(Guess)
          Guess = random.randint(Guess, Number+1)
          print("I'll try again, it's bigger")
      elif Guess == Number :
          print( "Got it, the value was: " + Guess)
          break
  else :
      print( "Got it! The value was:  " + Number)
      exit

guessing_game()
```